# AgGrid: Async Transactions are fundamentally flawed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

AgGrid provides async transactions.
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-high-frequency/#async-transactions.

```
applyTransactionAsync = (
    rowDataTransaction: RowDataTransaction<TData>,
    callback?: (res: RowNodeTransaction<TData>) => void
) => void;

interface RowDataTransaction<TData = any> {
  addIndex?: number | null;
  add?: TData[] | null;   // Rows to add 
  remove?: TData[] | null;
  update?: TData[] | null;
}
```

I am streaming data to my AgGrid received over websockets using async transaction.
Let's consider the below scenario -

- I receive a websocket response having multiple row updates.
- I read my grid's row ids, and accordingly create the transaction object `{add: [...], update: [...]}` Lets say row with rowId `X` is being added as a new row in above transaction.
- **Before grid finishes off applying the transaction**, lets say I receive another response over websocket, and since row `X` is still not added to my grid, I again create another transaction object which has row `X` in the `add` property's array.
- Now when both transactions will be applied, I see two issues -

  - Duplicate rows will be present with same rowId `X`, also warning thrown in console by AgGrid.
  - I am losing cell data for few columns, because both websocket messages may have updates for row `X` on disjoint set of columns.

Same issue exists with `update` scenario, but I think workaround is to actually fetch the `rowNode` and directly mutate `rowNode.data` so that you correctly process all websocket updates correctly. This is also discussed in another StackOverflow question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520617/ag-react-grid-applytransactionasync-api-replace-all-column-values-instead-of-col"

Anyone else faced this issue? What's the right way to tackle this?
Dropping Async Transactions solves the issue, but I like the idea of updating internal row data state asynchronously and triggering DOM update for them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it works better to keep your state separate from the grid component, and just bind the grid to your state, rather than letting the grid component be the repository of your state.

You can still trigger all of the updates at once by just replacing the state that's bound to the grid.

Comment: What you are suggesting is not recommended for high frequency updates as per AG Grid documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-row-data/#example-immutable-store---large-dataset:~:text=There%20is%20no%20equivalent,using%20Transaction%20Update.